# how to extract image of a child page in apostrophe cms

Tags: html, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I am doing a navigation bar in apostrophe every new page that is created requests of requirement an image for the icon that is a singleton of image widget this is the field:

```
{
  name: 'icon',
  label: 'Icon',
  type: 'singleton',
  widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
  options: {
             limit: 1,
             minSize: [200,200],
             aspectRatio: [1,1]
           }
}
```

when I want to bring it in my general template I am trying this:

```
{%- for tab in data.home._children -%}
  {%- set image = tab.icon or tab -%}
    <li>
      <a class="sidebar-main-link" href="{{ tab._url }}">
        <img class = "icon" src = "{{apos.attachments.url (image.attachment, {size: 'full'})}}" /> 
          {{tab.title}}
      </a>
     </ li>
{%- endfor -%}
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a new tutorial on the Apostrophe site covering this question in detail](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/thumbnails-and-areas-of-child-pages.html). Also see the [answer to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777917/how-to-access-custom-fields-in-a-data-home-children-loop).

Comment: It worked !, just mention that filters must be declared before types.

Comment: Filters and types options may be given in any order. But if you have a sample project showing otherwise please share a link and I'll have a look.