# How to display thumbnails of child pages?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am building a widget displaying tiles for all child pages of a given page. Clicking on a tile leads to the child page. All (child) pages have a thumbnail set. Each tile should display the thumbnail of the child page referenced.

I am having troubles extracting the thumbnails from the child pages. In particular,

```
{% for c in data.page._children %}
  {% set image = apos.images.first(c.thumbnail) %}
{% endfor %}
```

does not return an image. This is my configuration, copied from to the tutorial:

**Update: the following snippet is actually from `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js`, not from `lib/modules/apostrophe-images/index.js`.**

```
// lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js
module.exports = {
    types: [
        {name: 'home', label: 'Home'},
    ],
    filters: {
        children: {depth: 1,areas: ['thumbnail']}
    }
};
```

```
// lib/modules/apostrophe-custom-pages/index.js
module.exports = {
    beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
        options.addFields = [
            {
                name: 'thumbnail',
                type: 'singleton',
                widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
                options: {
                    aspectRatio: [1,1],limit: 1,size: 'full'
                }
            }
        ].concat(options.addFields||[]);
    }
};
```

If I add `{{ c.thumbnail | dump }}` I am getting `{"items":[{"by":"id","_id":"w686873719609971549","pieceIds":["cjz9ulv1j000z16ok52n2n575"],"relationships":{"cjz9ulv1j000z16ok52n2n575":{"left":816,"top":0,"width":3265,"height":3265,"x":null,"y":null}},"type":"apostrophe-images"}],"type":"area"}`; but `{{ apos.image.first(c.thumbnail)}}` does not give anything.

I have seen [how to extract image of a child page in apostrophe cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769896/how-to-extract-image-of-a-child-page-in-apostrophe-cms) and also followed the tutorial https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/thumbnails-and-areas-of-child-pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mentions:

```
// in lib/modules/apostrophe-images/index.js
```

But the code you have placed there belongs in `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js`. Specifically the `filters` option needs to be added there. You probably already have a `types` option there (which is unrelated to this particular issue).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The snippet is actually from `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js`, my bad. Question updated, the problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a small open source project on github so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks, I will, as soon as I get to it Tom.